# How to add a new line in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, window

So I have this code:

```
    heading = new JLabel("   Club Registration Form   ");
    heading.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    name = new JLabel(" Student Name: \n");
    name.setForeground(Color.white);
    yearLevel = new JLabel("<html><p> Year Level: </p></html>");
    yearLevel.setForeground(Color.white);
    section = new JLabel(" Section: ");
    section.setForeground(Color.white);
    club = new JLabel(" Preferred Club: ");
    club.setForeground(Color.white);
    nameForm = new JTextField(8);
    yearLevelForm = new JTextField(8);
    sectionForm = new JTextField(8);
    clubForm = new JTextField(8);
    
    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    
    add(heading, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    System.out.println("\n");
    add(name);
    add(nameForm);
    add(yearLevel);
    add(yearLevelForm);
    add(section);
    add(sectionForm);
    add(club);
    add(clubForm);
    add(submit);
```

As you can see, I tried the `\n`, the html method, and the print method. I wanted it to look like this:

[image: The textfields have their own lines]

The textfields have their own lines

It always appears in one line.

Comment: What "always appears on one line"?

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it since I'm not fluent in English. Instead of the JLabels and textfield in different lines (or rows), it appears in one continuous line. Imagine a text with '\n' in it, except that the '\n' doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use a `LayoutManager` to lay out the components the way you want them.  Instead of adding the components onto the `JFrame`, add them into a `JPanel` with an appropriate layout and add that `JPanel` into the `JFrame`.  Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for an introduction to layout.

Comment: I would suggest you can use the `GridBagLayout` as described in the tutorial link from above.